# Will I get better dynamodb throughput with this change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Right now I have mobile apps hitting a serverless aws lambda endpoint, writing 1 record.  At times, the mobile app writes several of these records over and over again (50-300).  An example of what 1 record looks like can be seen below:

```
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "miscValue": "1f2ea989-5b33-49e5-a88a-19c7594afd9d",
      "ratio": "1.7777777777777777",
      "new": true,
      "timestamp": "1524156952325"
    }
```

Now, if I change it, so that instead of writing 1 record per lambda call, it can write multiple records per call, and then do fewer calls, would that result in a lower dynamodb throughput?

Example Scenario:

The app could write `1 record per second for 100 seconds` vs `10 records per second for 10 seconds`.

AWS Documentation states:

> One write capacity unit represents one write per second for an item up
>   to 1 KB in size. If you need to write an item that is larger than 1
>   KB, DynamoDB will need to consume additional write capacity units. The
>   total number of write capacity units required depends on the item
>   size.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html

This leads me to believe, that since my record size is well under 1kb, if I made the change to do multiple records at a time I would see a signficant improvement in dynamodb throughput utilization.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

> One write capacity unit represents one write per second for an item **up to 1 KB in size**

No matter how you do it if you provision 1 write unit on the table you are allowed to write 1 item per second (besides burst capacity https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting). In case the item is bigger than 1 KB, you need more then 1 write unit (ceil(size / 1KB)) to write it. If the item is smaller than 1 KB you **anyway** need 1 write unit.

Comment: So the answer to my question is Yes, I would see a significant improvement correct?

Comment: If you have enough throughput allocated for each parallel request you get better throughput so the answer would be YES. Otherwise, if you just have 1 write unit provisioned the answer is NO.